# remember me not working simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I am using Devise for authentication. Trying to edit/create devise forms with simple_form.

this

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html=>{:class=>"form-vertical"}) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :email, :placeholder=>"Email", :label=>false %>
<%= f.input :password, :placeholder=>"Password", :label=>false %>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div style="display:inline"><%= f.input :remember_me, :inline_label => 'Yes, remember me'%></div>

<%end -%>
    <div><%= f.submit "Sign in", :class=>"pull-right btn btn-primary" %></div>
<div><%= link_to "Create an account", new_user_registration_path%></div>
<% end %>
```

is literally giving me; **Remember Me**, which should be checkbox

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's giving you an input field as well.  Are you sure you've got the correct data type to make `simple_form` and `devise` give you a checkbox?

Comment: i just replaced `f.check_box` that comes default with devise views

Comment: how am i suppose to check? browser remembers user anyway

Comment: yes `f.check_box` is working. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use

```
<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean %>
```